# Writing in TextField by using Buttons

Tags: java, button, javafx, textfield

I'm beginner in java and i stucked writing simple project in JavaFx - calculator.
I added Buttons filled with numbers and they should be showed in TextField when user click them.

But when i'm trying to check this idea they add every number from index 0. I thought maybe `field.getText().lenghth()` will solve this problem, but it didn't work. Sorry for my awful explanation. [Picture show it better](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYuJA.png)

```
int miejsce = obliczenia.getText().length();

    cyfra0.setOnAction(e -> obliczenia.insertText(miejsce, "0"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
TextField textField = new TextField("123");
Button button = new Button("4");
button.setOnAction(click -> {
    String textFieldNewString = textField.getText() + button.getText();
    textField.setText(textFieldNewString);
}):
```

This will add the Buttons Text to the TextField

Comment: @Tymek No problem. i'd appreciate if you mark it as the right anwer then , just telling you this since you seem to be new here :)

Comment: Oh sorry, didn't knew about this :)